# MATLAB script does not terminate on Mac

Tags: macos, matlab, terminate

I am running this on MATLAB 2014a, and the command line does not return.

```
a = 0;
while (1)
    a = a + 1;
    if (a ~= 2)
        continue;
    end;
end;
```

There is no response when I do <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> (or any other common combination of keyboard keys). How can get the script to terminate?

Comment: Related: [What is a “tight loop”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2212973/2278029). Do you want want your loop to exit normally on it's own or do you want to be able to abort your script/function using control-C?

Comment: I just tried this with R2013a on a linux box and got the same behavior. I suspect one would need to be intimately familiar with the matlab interpreter in order to know why the interrupt signal does not reach it.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: Because it's a tight loop –see the link in my comment above. The loop needs to have an explicit `pause` or call to another function (e.g., something involving graphics) that allow the command window sufficient time/resources to interrupt the running code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "continue", try "break".

Here's my reasoning:

"continue" temporarily interrupts the execution of a program loop, skipping any remaining statements in the body of the loop for the ***current pass only***.

So it doesn't exit the loop completely, it skips any remaining code in the loop and then *re-evaluates the condition of the while loop, which in your case **is always true**.*

In contrast, break exits the loop completely.

Another way to go about it is to rewrite your loop statement, for example:

```
a = 0;
while a~=2
  a = a + 1;
end
```

Not sure why it wouldn't cease running with ctrl-c though. I expect that your script has run for such a long time that your machine might be getting progressively less responsive. Hinted by this article: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/stop-execution.html